# go to jsp page by hitting back button

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

I have `2 jsp pages and one Servlet`. I am fetching data from database by servlet and sending result to `result.jsp` page where i am displaying result. But i want to add a `Back button` in `result.jsp` , by clicking `back button` i want to go to `index.jsp`, but problem is when i am clicking back button everytime a message is coming `Confirm form submission` and it is irritating me. How can i avoid this `Confirm form submission`? perhaps it is coming as processing is done in servlet.

index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="Student">

<input type="text" name="studentname"/>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>

</form>
```

Student servlet

```
 String student_name=request.getParameter("studentname");

  -------fetching data from database------------
  -------------------sending to result.jsp------

  String nextJSP = "/result.jsp";
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
      dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

result.jsp

```
 //displaying data here

<form action="index.jsp">

 <input type="submit" value="back"/>// a back button is here which is going to index.jsp   
</form>
```

**EDIT**

From `result.jsp` i am going to another page `result1.jsp` like below

In `result.jsp` i have written the following:

```
<a  href="result1.jsp.jsp?a code=<%out.println(student_name);%>"><%out.println(student_name);%></a>
```

By clicking the above hyperlink i went to `result1.jsp`

I want to add a back button here(in result1.jsp) and after clicking i want to do to result.jsp, but when clicking back button i am getting `Confirm form submission` every time. I have written the following in `result1.jsp`

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

Still i am getting that message `Confirm form submission`. How can i avoid this? I want to go to `result.jsp` directly with out this message. How is it possible?

Comment: Some answers for the back (hard index.jsp) are given. **To prevent that browser go-back triggers a second form submit**, do after a form submit validation handling a `sendRedirect` to the result page. This is a common technique.

Answer (score 8):

you can also use this to go one page back

```
<button type="button" name="back" onclick="history.back()">back</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write the below code that let's you to go `index.jsp` on your `result.jsp` page

```
<a href="index.jsp">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<button type="button" 
    name="back" 
    onclick='window.location='<your_path>/index.jsp'>back</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a back button to go index.jsp, why not just make a normal link?

```
<a href="index.jsp">Back</a>
```

There is only two way to get rid of the message, normal link or `window.location`. If the previous page is always the same, you don't need to use complicated function client side. If the page could be different, just post the link to result.jsp and use it to actually print a back link!

EDIT :

previous.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="Student">
<input type="hidden" name="back" value="previous.jsp" />
<input type="text" name="studentname"/>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

result.jsp

```
out.println("<a href=\"" + request.getParameter("back") + "\">Back</a>");
```

Comment: Just tried your code now...

out.println("<a href=\"home.jsp" ++ "\">Back</a>");

just this line will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way to create a goBack button using the method goBack(). This is the same as clicking the "Back button" used on the top of your browser.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    /* The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list. 
       This is the same as clicking the "Back button" in your browser.
    */
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back()
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

    <p>Notice that clicking on the Back button here will not result in any action, because there is no previous URL in the history list.</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common `button`.

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

With `history.go(-1)`, your browser will simply display previous page by reading from cache, it will not resubmit your data to the server, thus, no `Confirm form submission` will happen.

**EDIT**

I was wrong!

All you need is a client side redirect, you may write something like this in your `result.jsp` after it handles the form submitted from `index.jsp`:

```
response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
```

So you will need a parameter to help you in `result.jsp` to tell whether it is a simple *display* request or a form submission, something like this:

```
String action = request.getParameter(action);
if("submit".equals(action)) {
    // handle form data
    response.sendRedirect("result.jsp");
} else {
    // other code to display content of result.
}
```

In your `index.jsp`, it would be something like this:

```
....
<form action="result.jsp?action=submit" ...>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you please little bit explain why `onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"` ? what's it's meaning?

Comment: It was actually `window.history.go(-1)`, where window is the current window of your browser, note, you can always omit `window`. This feature is implemented by your browser, `history.go(-1)` means `go backwards by 1 step in the window's history.`

Comment: no no it is still coming `confirm form submission` actually i have edited my question

Comment: @Neevak..I have updated my question..please see..if possible please give me a solution

Comment: i am not getting your answer..actually when i added your back button code then nothing happened. same problem again

Comment: Yea, I was wrong, because hitting the Back button in the browser is the same as what `history.go(-1)` does. see my edited answer, you need a client side redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that form submit confirmation with Safari (not with IE/Chrome/FF).

The work around is submitting your form with "get" method. Of course this is only valid for "small" forms (max 2048 K).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.jsp" class="btn btn-success">
    Back
</a>
```

with bootstrap.css from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)