# How to create parent-child relationship and handle in a Website created using JSP?

Tags: java, .net, jsp, project, vs-web-site-project

How to code for the back arrow icon so that once a process is done on the webpage it does not go back to the steps of that process instead redirect to the parent page i.e. home.jsp etc.

Comment: It might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513745/go-to-jsp-page-by-hitting-back-button.

Comment: @SachinKumar Actually that is a different problem. Here I want to control which page should be shown when the back button is clicked.